# Error running MCPMOD in R Dosefinding package

Tags: r

I am trying to get the MCPMOD method of the Dosefinding package working. When I run MCPMOD with one model in the my_models object the method works;

```
my_models <- Mods(emax = c(0.2,0.7,200),
              doses = doses,placEff=0.1,maxEff = 0.9,fullMod=TRUE) 
MCPMod(adose, response2, as.data.frame(simdat), my_models, Delta=0.1, selModel = "AIC" ,alpha=0.025)
```

But when I include 1 or more models it does not;

```
my_models <- Mods(linear=c(0.2,0.001),emax = c(0.2,0.7,200),
              doses = doses,placEff=0.1,maxEff = 0.9,fullMod=TRUE)
MCPMod(adose, response2, as.data.frame(simdat), my_models, Delta=0.1, selModel = "AIC" ,alpha=0.025)
```

It gives the error;

```
Error in match.arg(direction) : 'arg' must be of length 1
```

The data look like;

[image]

Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks to whoever spared the time to downvote this post - I thought this was a legitimate question when faced with an ambiguous error message to which I couldn't find an explanation for online.

Anyway for the benfit of others I believe the problem was related with the "fullmod=TRUE" line in the call to the "Mods" method. The following code works;

```
my_models <- Mods(linear=NULL,emax = c(200),quadratic=c(-0.000004/0.0028),
              doses = doses,placEff=0.2,maxEff = 0.5,fullMod=FALSE)

MCPMod(adose, response2, as.data.frame(simdat), my_models, Delta=0.1, selModel = "AIC" ,alpha=0.025)
```

The difference above is that for each model type only one parameter is provided to the "Mods" function since the full model versions are not being used (fullmod=FALSE). From providing the placebo effect (placEff=0.2) and the maximum dose effect (maxEff=0.7) the method then back calculates the remaining parameters in the model.

Given this new knowledge I thought perhaps the first error was related to using the placEff and maxEff arguments when at the same time supplying all the model parameters (I don't think both are required). However the following code also does not work;

```
my_models <- Mods(linear=c(0.2,0.001),quadratic=c(0.2,0.0028,-0.000004),
           logistic=c(0.2, 0.7, 200, 50),emax = c(0.2,0.7,200),
           doses = doses,fullMod=TRUE)
MCPMod(adose, response2, as.data.frame(simdat), my_models, Delta=0.1, selModel = "AIC" ,alpha=0.025)
```